# Generate a list of objects of python builitins that can be called without arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of python built-in type objects as [{},(),[],'',0.....] that can be called without arguments

I'm not sure how to write the comprehension . I have the following code

```
[getattr(___builtins___,x)() for x in dir(___builtins___)]
```

Certain elements are not callable and some take arguments so the above wont work

Comment: ... why?  What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way to get where you're going than by way of where you're headed.

Comment: I'm doing this for fun. Kojiro gave an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As g.d.d.c implies in the comments, this is probably an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But if you're doing it just for fun, don't use a list comprehension. Write a generator that handles exceptions:

```
def no_arg_builtins():
  for builtin in dir(__builtins__):
    o = getattr(__builtins__, builtin)
    if callable(o):
      try:
        yield o()
      except TypeError:
        pass # Called incorrectly
    else:
      pass # not callable
```

Alternatively, if you just want a list of the builtin types, consider using the [types module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), or filter where the builtins are 'type' types:

```
(t for t in dir(__builtins__) if type(getattr(__builtins__, t)) == type([].__class__))
```

Finally, you can use [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to determine specific things about the arity of a callable.